# HTML CSS: Make Google Icon into Button without Rectangle around it

Tags: html, css, svg, button, google-material-icons

How do I make a Google Icon into a Button? However, do not want a rectangular box around the button. The icon pixels will be a button itself.

```css
.testdelete {
     font-family: Material Icons;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<span class="testdelete">
 delete
</span>
```

Link below places a rectangle around button, something don't want.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_icon_buttons.asp

Comment: it sounds you are looking for `<a>` tag (?)

Comment: it seems that every font is rendered in a rectangle. did you try using `.svg` instead?

Comment: all google icons are svg by nature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use an  tag to simulate a button?

```js
$( ".testdelete" ).click(function() {
  $("p").hide();
});
```

```css
.testdelete {
     font-family: Material Icons;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">



<a class="testdelete">
 delete
</a>

<p class="hi">To be deleted</p>
```

You can also use `<button>tweet</button>` and handle the background and border removal with css:

```
.button {
background: none;
border: none;
color: black;
}
```

Comment: How it doesn't work? I gave it a dummy function the hide the <p> below, you can pass whatever function! 

In any case you can also use <button></button> and remove the background and border, I will update my answer.

Comment: thanks, is there anyway to conduct this with CSS / html? trying to refrain from js unless needed

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer! Be aware that if you're performing actions (delete in this case) in the database, html and css won't be enough. I need to either make a request to the server via ajax (better user experience) or  for example through PHP.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<a href="#" class="button">
```

TWEET!

style.css:

```
.button { 
font-family: Material Icons;
vertical-align:middle; 
cursor: pointer; 
}

.text:hover{  
cursor: pointer; 
}
```

Comment: can we try it for the simple delete icon above in question? seems like this has a lot of animation effects not needed, looking for bare simple answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>

<i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
<i class="material-icons">favorite</i>
<i class="material-icons">attachment</i>
<i class="material-icons">computer</i>
<i class="material-icons">traffic</i>

</body>
</html>
```